# ScrollViewer object to scroll to the bottom , Referring the ListView's child visual object in the ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am rewriting an application using MVVM architecture. How do I implement the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` method to get the the listview's child visual object to scroll to the bottom in the ViewModel (MVVM). I moved this code from the code behind to the ViewModel. I need help with referring to the ListView object in my viewmodel without referring to the windows control by fixing the commented code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Jumps to pending feature.
/// </summary>
private bool JumpToPending()
{
    foreach (Book book in BookList)
    {
        if (book.Verified == VerifiedType.Pending)
        {
            //By scrolling to the bottom first, we will ensure the selected feature will appear at the top of the listview
            //instead of the bottom.
            //ScrollViewer sv =   VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listofBooks, 0), 0) as ScrollViewer;
            //sv.ScrollToBottom();

            //listofBooks.SelectedItem = book;
            //listofBooks.ScrollIntoView(book);
            //sv.LineUp();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bind `SelectedItem` to a property in your view model, the newly selected item should automatically be scrolled into view when the selection changes.  If that behavior is not sufficient, you should keep the scrolling logic in the view; it does not belong in the view model, as it is specific to that particular view design. You may, however, want to add an event in your view model that your view can react to in order to kick off the selection/scrolling logic.

Comment: A RelayCommand(JumpToPendingCmd) is fired when the user invokes a context menu item(JumpToPending) on the list view. This function is called and the item selected in the list view is bound to the SelectedItem property in the view model. The item is now scrolling to the view, But I am not sure if that behavior is sufficient as you said.I will take a deeper look at this. Thanks @Mike.